# Duda scanner se me interrumpe

Tags: java, java-swing, entrada, matriz, scanner

Al intentar hacer un problema utilizo el scanner para meter datos por la entrada pero llega a un punto en el que se interrumpe y ya no va.

```
int i=0;
int j=0;
int n=0;
int [][] prueba = null;
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in))
{
    do {
        n=s.nextInt();
        prueba = new int[n][n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
                //  System.out.println(s.nextInt());
                prueba[i][j]=s.nextInt();
            //  s.skip("\n");
            }

        }   
    }   while(s.hasNextInt());
    System.out.println(Deontrologia(prueba,n)); 
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

}

Este es la parte en la que me da el problema al pasarle
5
1 1 1 1 1
2 3 3 3 2
2 3 5 3 2
2 3 3 3 2
1 1 1 1 1
por la entrada cuando llega a la ultima fila, coje y se interrumpe la ejecucion sin dar fallo y no entiendo por que.

Comment: para que el uso de do while? si queras rellenar la matriz no es necesario su uso

Comment: El método **hasNextInt()** de la clase java.util.Scanner devuelve verdadero si el siguiente token en la entrada de este escáner se puede asumir como un valor Int de la base dada,y como siempre ingresas un numero estas ocasionando un loop

Comment: Lo del do while lo hice por probar ya que casi nunca lo hago y ya solucione la duda muchas gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Hola Fer! El problema no me es claro, al intentar ejecutar el código como lo tienes (exceptuando el llamado a la clase Deontrologia la cual no tengo), el scanner se comporta como yo esperaria. Nos puedes indicar mas información por favor? quizas detalles de la excepción si se esta generando alguna, o el punto en el código donde se presenta la interrupción.
Puedes adicionar `e.printStackTrace()` despues de `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` para obtener un par de detalles adicionales. Saludos!

Comment: Camilo Gonzáles
No te preocupes lo solucione no sabia muy bien como funcionaba el scanner y no entendí que en la entrada hay que poner un salto de linea por eso se me interrumpia.